# Button Dynamic Padding/Height Issue on Mobile

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

For some reason `button` elements have extra "padding" or "height"  when compared to other elements with the same value **if the value is not fixed but dynamic.**

I have verified the issue myself in Chrome and Safari on iOS, and one of my friends verified the issue in Chrome on Android.

## A. Fixed value for padding

```
span, button {
  padding: 16px;
}
```

[image]

The height of the `button` on the right is `1px` more, but both elements are otherwise equal according to a console log, which actually seems to be the case.

*Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/LYPpyqW).*

## B. Dynamic value for padding

```
span, button {
  padding: calc(var(--gap) / 2);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) {
  html {
    --gap: calc(10px + (40 - 10) * (100vw - 0px) / (1200 - 0));
  }
}
```

[image]

Clearly the `button` on the right is much taller than the `span` element on the left, even though console says they're basically equal, and ***the exact same value has been applied to both elements...***

*Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/wvwKdjX).*

- The only difference between A and B is that B doesn't use a fixed value.
- This odd behavior can be observed on both iOS and Android.
- Setting `appearance` to `none` before styling has no effect.
- Everything works as expected on desktop browsers.

**Does anybody know what is going on here?**

---

## Updates

Applying a `line-height: 1.15` and `margin: 0` to the `button` element reduces the discrepancy.

Oddly, console claims the `span` element is still `1px` wider (and `2px` taller), even though they're effectively the exact same width if you overlay the two elements.

The text of the `span` element is `1px` or `2px` lower than the text in the `button` element, which makes sense because the `span` is `1px` or `2px` taller.

```
button {
  ...
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
```

[image]

*Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/BaBzKEZ).*

I would just add a pixel or two to the `button` height, but unfortunately the height of many elements on my website is determined by a combination of a dynamic `font-size` and `padding`. And I'd rather not have to constantly run a bunch of JS in the background to dynamically calculate the height for every element on the fly.

Comment: Not sure that is the reason but in your codepen, you've closed your button with a `</span>`.

Comment: @Mig thanks for pointing that out. however, the issue persists

Comment: No worries, I don't have the issue so I cannot test, but it sounds like a default that is different. Maybe a border or something. What you can try is to set the `appearance` of the button to `none` with all the prefix versions. If you do this, then it should behave like a span. Also make sure they are bother either `inline` or `inline-block` but not a mix of both. It may not change anything, but just to make sure they behave the same.

Comment: did you try with a https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ ?

Comment: @Mig ive tried all of that before. unfortunately it has no effect whatsoever. the issue doesnt seem to have anything to do with the default styling of any particular browser or OS. the issue persists across multiple browsers and multiple OSs.

Comment: Have you tried using em vs px?

Comment: @HugoGresse i havent. i never knew that existed. but ive now taken a look at it to get some ideas. i think it actually does have something to do with default styles, specifically the `line-height`. if i just normalize the `line-height` between the two, theyre much closer to the exact same dimensions. omg so silly. why would buttons have a different default `line-height` than span elements. makes zero sense.

Comment: @jdpy19 i havent. i think it may have something to do with a combination of default styles such as `line-height` and something else

Comment: I would assume the default wasn't different but something was overriding it. That said, sometimes setting the first line of the element's css to `all:initial;` (hard reset) helps you start from scratch on styling. I also believe buttons have a 1px border by default and span's do not.

Comment: @BryceHowitson `all: initial` didn't seem to do anything

Comment: @HugoGresse i tried applying all of that styling. doesnt seem to do the trick, even though `line-height: 1.15` alone reduces the discrepancy

Comment: @jdpy19 switching to `em` instead of `px` doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me try to support you with this issue.

**What is happening here**

How line-height is calculated by the browser is depending on the font definition and the browser/os itself. Try setting font-family: sans-serif instead of Arial just to try out. [Further information on line-height](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align)

**`line-height` is not applied on `span`** unless you're changing its display property from inline (default) to something like inline-* or block or it is part of another formatting context like flexbox.

> A block container element that directly contains inline-level
>   content—such as inline boxes, atomic inlines, and text
>   runs—establishes an inline formatting context. The line-height
>   property specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the
>   element.

[Further information on Inline Layout Box Model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-inline/#model)

[Glossary for definitions like block level, inline etc.](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display-3/#glossary)

Side note:
Also pay attention to button css defaults like margin-top, margin-bottom that can play a role and the fact that button does not inherit font styles per default.

**Possible solutions**

My initial idea was finding that value for Arial and setting it as line-height explicitly on button so that it would match the default one on span. But apparently it's not possible to rely on browsers calculating line-height the same on several devices even if you know the default value.

- `display: inline-block` on span and use the same line-height on both elements.
- Use flexbox and make use of elements having the same height.

Comment: wow, applying `line-height` to both, and `inline-flex` to the `span`, and `margin: 0` to the `button` worked!! its because elements that default to `inline` dont have a `line-height` applied to them because they belong to another context??? can you add more info regarding this for other users please, maybe some documentation or whatever, then ill select as the answer

Answer (score 0):

By default button is having display:inline-block(inspect the button element by default every element have some default styles) where as span element is having display:inline. for inline elements line-height will not work. try to convert the span element in to inline-block element.

```
span{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

you can also use css float or flex.

**more info on inline-elements:-** 
Inline elements don't start on new lines, meaning that they'll line up right next to each other on the same line if there's enough room for them. If you don't understand the different rules that apply to inline elements, your CSS can be incredibly frustrating. For example, inline elements can't take a top or bottom margins, or width or height properties. But, they can still by styled with left and right margins as well as with padding. If you didn't know the specific rules that inline elements follow, you'd surely have a headache.

For more differences between inline and block level elements read the below article.
https://codeburst.io/block-level-and-inline-elements-the-difference-between-div-and-span-2f8502c1f95b

Comment: edit your answer to include more information and i will up vote it

Answer (score 0):

Line height / pixels depends on browser and OS, so height varies on both button & span.

Try Below code, that will help you to get height

span, button{ display:inline-block; padding:0 15px; height:45px; line-height:45px;}

```css
span {
          margin-right: 5px;
        }
    
        button {
          outline: none;
          border: none;
        }
    
        span, button {
          display:inline-block;  
          padding: 0 15px;
          height:45px;
          line-height:45px;
          font-family: arial;
          font-size: .704265875rem;
          color: #fff;
          border-radius: 5px;
          background: #4d4d4d;
          -webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none;
        }
```

```html
<span>NEGOTIATE</span><button>NEGOTIATE</button>
```